# SQL Error (1442) , any solution?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I created this trigger in MySQL (after update on table product):

```
BEGIN
 set @parentid := (select parent_id from product where product_id = new.product_id);
 if (old.price <> new.price) then
  update product set price=new.price where product_id = @parentid and price > new.price;
 end if;
END
```

But, when I update price, I get this error

> : SQL Error (1442) Can't update table 'product' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger. */

I created two tables and two triggers like:

`Trigger 1` (after update on table product):

```
BEGIN
 if (old.price <> new.price) then
    insert into product_price
    (product_id, price , date_added)
    values
    (new.product_id, new.price, SYSDATE());
 end if;
END
```

`Trigger 2` (after insert on table `product_price`):

```
BEGIN
 SET @parentid := (select parent_id from product where product_id = new.product_id);
 if (@parentid >0) then
  update  product set price=new.price where product_id in (select @parentid);
 end if;
END
```

But, I got that error again.

I really need to update parent price when child price changed, do you have any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What value do you want product.price to have after you've just updated it explicitly?

Comment: @JRD He's not making any changes to the row that's being inserted or updated, he's trying to update the parent product.

Comment: i have some child products, and i need to display cheapest price of children on parent product.

Comment: @Barmar I see. Seems like a cascading nightmare, if the hierarchy is more than 1 level deep.  Can you derive the cheapest price on select, instead of trying to maintain it?

Comment: @JRD i am trying to change an existing code, this is very hard work to change all codes to display another query, if i could use something like this triggers, it will be safer and easier.

Comment: @JRD That's probably why MySQL doesn't allow it, because it could cause multiple recursive triggers.

Comment: @AliMayel As the answer states, you are not going to be able to do this with triggers. This is a consequence of your data model.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use triggers, since you need to update the same table that is being updated. You need to move this logic into the application code or use a stored procedure instead of triggers.

Comment: its very hard process, because there are very different ways to change prices, like (in application, from out with injecting to sql and ...)

Comment: You do not have a choice, unless you move child and parent prices to separate tables.